# A div height matching issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote some javascript to match the height of two columns and it is not working. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible but I don't understand exactly what the problem is. I am attaching the snippet of javascript as well as a link to the jsfiddle. Please let me know if you see anything wrong with my code.

```
function matchColumHeights('.column1', '.column2') {

    var column1Height = $('.column1').height();
    var column2Height = $('.column2').height();

    if (column1Height < column2Height) {
        $('.column1').height(column2Height);
    } else {
        $('.column2').height(column1Height);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqypw5q2/1/

Comment: the divs has both column1 class, and also your function params are not correct

Comment: open your browser console in the fiddle

Comment: `.column2 { loat: left; }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you haven't included the `jQuery` library (so you have a reference error with the `$` symbol)
- you don't call the function `matchColumHeights` (and your code is not executed)
- A `.column2` element is missing (so the comparison don't work as you expect)

As a side note you have also a typo in your css (`loat` instead of `float`) and your parent should be wider than `700px` (since you've applied some margin and padding to your columns)

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/0e2vLyvb/2/

Comment: And there is no need to pass params to function.

Comment: I still dont see the divs height matching. Also I am horrible with syntax and am trying to get better. Where is my syntax error exactly?

Comment: One is still taller than the other.

Comment: @user3174713 have you seen my example?

Comment: No I have not Fabrizio